# I Am Able To Go Outside Array Bounds

Tags: c++, arrays

**Given two strings, write a method to decide if one is an anagram/permutation of the other. This is my approach:**

I wrote this function to check if 2 strings are anagrams (such as dog and god).

In ascii, a to z is 97 - 122.

Basically I have an array of bools that are all initially false. Everytime I encounter a char in string1, it marks it as true.

To check if its an anagram, I check if any chars of string2 are false (should be true if encountered in string1).

I'm not sure how but this works too: arr[num] = true; (shouldnt work because I dont take into account that ascii starts at 97 and thus goes out of bounds).

***(Side note: is there a better approach than mine?)***

**EDIT: Thanks for all the responses! Will be carefully reading each one. By the way: not an assignment. This is a problem from a coding interview practice book**

```
bool permutation(const string &str1, const string &str2)
{
    // Cannot be anagrams if sizes are different
    if (str1.size() != str2.size())
        return false;

    bool arr[25] = { false };

    for (int i = 0; i < str1.size(); i++) // string 1
    {
        char ch = (char)tolower(str1[i]); // convert each char to lower
        int num = ch; // get ascii
        arr[num-97] = true; 
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < str2.size(); i++) // string 2
    {
        char ch = (char)tolower(str2[i]); // convert char to lower
        int num = ch; // get ascii
        if (arr[num-97] == false) 
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: See [this](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/294094/40065) about buffer overflow detection

Comment: Why would you expect it to not work?  C does no bounds checking.  If you go out of bounds, you'll just update whatever memory happens to be in that spot (or, possibly, get a segfault / access violation if the address is outside your process).  Assuming it doesn't AV, if it doesn't crash, it's just pure dumb luck.

Comment: Regards the side question, compare `good` and `godd`.

Comment: If there are repeating characters in the string like "ddog", your algorithm may fail i.e. "ddog" and "dogg" will be accepted by your algorithm as anagrams. Use an array of `int` to store the count of each letter instead of just their occurences.

Comment: Another approach is to sort each string and then compare the strings for equality. Might be a little slower but needs no additional storage.

Comment: Instead of `num-97`, use `num-'a'`. It's a lot clearer. Still wrong on those weird IBM machines but who cares about those?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing inherent in C++ arrays that prevents you from writing beyond the end of them. But, in doing so, you violate the *contract* you have with the compiler and it is therefore free to do what it wishes (undefined behaviour).

You can get bounds checking on "arrays" by using the `vector` class, if that's what you need.

As for a better approach, it's probably better if your array is big enough to cover *every* possible character (so you don't have to worry about bounds checking) and it shouldn't so much be a truth value as a count, so as to handle duplicate characters within the strings. If it's just a truth value, then `here` and `her` would be considered anagrams.

Even though you state it's *not* an assignment, you'll still learn more if you implement it yourself, so it's pseudo-code only from me. The basic idea would be:

```
def isAnagram (str1, str2):
    # Different lengths means no anagram.

    if len(str1) not equal to len(str2):
        return false

    # Initialise character counts to zero.

    create array[0..255] (assumes 8-bit char)
    for each index 0..255:
        set count[index] to zero

    # Add 1 for all characters in string 1.

    for each char in string1:
        increment array[char]

    # Subtract 1 for all characters in string 2.

    for each char in string2:
        decrement array[char]

    # Counts will be all zero for an anagram.

    for each index 0..255:
        if count[index] not equal to 0:
            return false
    return true
```

Answer (score 1):

Working approach : with zero additional cost.

```
bool permutation(const std::string &str1, const std::string &str2)
{
    // Cannot be anagrams if sizes are different
    if (str1.size() != str2.size())
        return false;

    int arr[25] = {0 };

    for (int i = 0; i < str1.size(); i++) // string 1
    {
        char ch = (char)tolower(str1[i]); // convert each char to lower
        int num = ch; // get ascii
        arr[num-97] = arr[num-97] + 1 ;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < str2.size(); i++) // string 2
    {
        char ch = (char)tolower(str2[i]); // convert char to lower
        int num = ch; // get ascii
        arr[num-97] = arr[num-97] - 1 ;
    }

    for (int i =0; i< 25; i++) {
        if (arr[i] != 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `C` and `C++` both doesn't carry out the `index-out-of-bounds`.

> It is the duty of the programmer to make sure that the program logic doesn't cross the legitimate limits. It is the programmer who need to make checks for the **violations**.

**Improved Code**:

```
bool permutation(const string &str1, const string &str2)
{
    // Cannot be anagrams if sizes are different
    if (str1.size() != str2.size())
        return false;

    int arr[25] = { 0 };                  //<-------- Changed

    for (int i = 0; i < str1.size(); i++) // string 1
    {
        char ch = (char)tolower(str1[i]); // convert each char to lower
        int num = ch; // get ascii
        arr[num-97] += 1;                 //<-------- Changed
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < str2.size(); i++) // string 2
    {
        char ch = (char)tolower(str2[i]); // convert char to lower
        int num = ch; // get ascii
        arr[num-97] = arr[num-97] - 1 ;   //<-------- Changed
    }

    for (int i =0; i< 25; i++) {          //<-------- Changed
        if (arr[i] != 0) {                //<-------- Changed
            return false;                 //<-------- Changed
        }
    }       
    return true;
}
```